# PG-Promise Proc Erroring Out with Unknown Parameter Type

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, stored-procedures, pg-promise

We are attempting to write a PostgreSQL Procedure to insert data into a table. We have created the procedure and ran said procedure with the variables below and it inserts just fine. However, when we try to use `pg-promise` with our express server, our string parameters are being read as `unknown`. When we iterate over the post body, we see that each parameter is reading as the type we expect to go in, and PostgreSQL is reading integer correctly, but it isn't reading string correctly. I've attempted to use the `as.text` function and it sends in the parameter value as `"''"` but that still reads as unknown. Is there something we are missing to successfully post the data?

```
let createInspection = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let params = [];
    for (let prop in req.body) {
      console.log(typeof req.body[prop]);
      params.push(req.body[prop]);
    }
    console.log(params)
    let data = await db.proc('Inspections_Create', params);
    res.status(200)
    .json({
      status: 'success',
      data: data,
      message: 'Inserted Inspection'
    });
  }
  catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like something that you are missing on the server-side, and not the library. That's the server telling you of using a non-existing procedure signature. Maybe you got the name wrong, due to your odd use of capitals (against the standard). If the name uses capitals, you can try `db.oneOrNull('CALL "Inspections_Create"($1:csv)', [params])`, see what happens.

Comment: P.S. You need to check the procedure's exact name in the server. Most likely you've got something messed up with your use of capitals.

Comment: You should include here the script that creates the procedure (just the header).

Comment: It was the procedure typing. That's what the issue was. I did the db.oneOrNull and that worked for me.

Comment: Sounds like you picked an unneeded work-around. And you couldn't get a proper solution, because I asked you for details on the name, and you didn't provide it, so couldn't get a better advise.